# cannot save data entered in a form that was opened using dao.

Tags: vba

let me start by saying that i am new to access vba coding, so bear with me.
i open a form using dao code opened to a new record. however, i cannot seem to be able to save the record no matter what i try.

```
'opened a Form_MyForm for a new record.
dim frm as new form
set frm = new Form_MyForm 
frm.recordset.addnew
frm.visible = true
```

On the "Form_MyForm" save button, i have the following code

```
private sub save_click()
me.dirty = (me.dirty = false)
docmd.close acForm, me.name
end sub
```

everything seems to work ok (including the ID, hwnd, etc) except that nothing gets saved on the table. if i use docmd.openform to open the form, then the code works...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you create two forms, one of the type form, the other of the type of your form.

Anyway, I would recommend using the DoCmd.Openform command.
Normally you would not have to save any data. (On the contrary, if you want to not save the data you would use

```
  If Me.Dirty = True Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

If you need to access the form from vba after you opened it, use

```
Set frm = Application.Forms("My_Form")
```

And if you want to close the form programmatically again use DoCmd.close

Comment: thank you johanness for responding.

but i am bit confused about your first sentence. are you saying that i need to create two forms (or that i created two forms). either way, can you explain it to me further what you mean? i would really appreciate it.

b.t.w. i am using dao because i am opening multiple instances of My_Form using allen browne's approach. as far as i know, DoCmd.Openform does not support multiple instances. :(

Comment: You use the keyword new twice, thus creating two forms (the first one will be eliminated by access as soon as it is not stored anywhere (you assign the correct form to the variable frm) but you dont need it twice. To open multiple instances of a form you have to have a variable for each. Its just a question where to store that variable... Please edit your question to include what you want to do and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: johanness, you really help me, especially with [frm = application.froms("My_Form")]. i created a new simple DB to check out my code, and i realize that my problem may be interaction between frm.RecordSet.AddNew and how Access handle form. in short, if the frm.RecordSet.ID is "X", then the form's ID is "X+1". when i save the form, then it stores two records X (which is a blank) and X+1 (which is a updated one). i think i was running into a problem because i have "required" field on the form. i don't even know if this is the right forum to discuss this... any pointer would be appreciated. thanx